# Merging Resource Dictionary from Resource in Nuget Package

Tags: xaml, uwp

So I have a Resource Dictionary in another assembly. It looks like this:

```
<ResourceDictionary
Source="ms-appx:///MyStuff.UI.Common/Styles/Shared.xaml" />
```

I am trying to remove the project reference and add the reference using a nuget package. After I do that, I get the following runtime error:

```
Failed to assign to property 'Windows.UI.Xaml.ResourceDictionary.Source' because the type 'Windows.Foundation.String' cannot be assigned to the type 'Windows.Foundation.Uri'. [Line: 12 Position: 37]
```

How can I get this Resource Dictionary in a separate assembly merged in when its in a nugget package? I figured there wouldn't be a difference.

Answer (score 0):

XAML Merged Dictionaries are trickier than they seem. All is well if you are referencing a local project, then your ResourceDictionary Source= paths well.

If you are referencing an external DLL (not in-solution), the referenced DLL folder must also have all *.xml, *.xr.xml, *.xbf, *.jpg/png/gif, etc.

I had **major** Source= Uri syntax problems when I migrated a in-solution project to an external DLL reference. Also, my referenced DLL folder didn't have all of the resource files in the correct folders.

The procedure I follow is: 1. Reference DLL containing the merged dictionaries (XAML style sheets). 2. Ensure the reference path has all required files. 3. Add the merged dictionary reference to your App.xaml

```
<Application.Resources>
    <ResourceDictionary>
        <ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
            <ResourceDictionary Source="ms-appx:///NAMESPACE_HERE/Styles.xaml"/>
        </ResourceDictionary.MergedDictionaries>
    </ResourceDictionary>
</Application.Resources>
```

This PostBuild.bat file describes how I have VS copy all required files on successful build:

```
Echo Starting: PostBuildEvent: Call $(ProjectDir)PostBuild.Bat $(ProjectDir) $(OutDir) $(TargetPath) $(RootNameSpace)
Echo With Parameters: %1 %2 %3 %4

REM ***
REM *** Variables
REM ***
SET BuildLocationBin=..\..\..\..\..\..\..\..\bin

REM ***
Echo *** Publish to Bin
REM ***
MD %BuildLocationBin%
%WINDIR%\system32\attrib.exe %BuildLocationBin%\*.* -r /s
%WINDIR%\system32\xcopy.exe %1Properties\*.rd.xml %BuildLocationBin%\%4\Properties\*.* /s/r/y
%WINDIR%\system32\xcopy.exe %1%2*.png %BuildLocationBin%\%4\*.* /s/r/y
%WINDIR%\system32\xcopy.exe %1%2*.xbf %BuildLocationBin%\%4\*.* /s/r/y
%WINDIR%\system32\xcopy.exe %1%2*.xml %BuildLocationBin%\%4\*.* /s/r/y
%WINDIR%\system32\xcopy.exe %3 %BuildLocationBin%\*.* /s/r/y
%WINDIR%\system32\xcopy.exe %1%2*.pri %BuildLocationBin%\*.* /s/r/y

Echo *** Postbuild Complete ***
```

Hope this helps!